QFontDialog shows fonts for unsupported locale
My laptop is on Gentoo Linux KDE with Qt 5.15.2, and I have English locales as well as Russian.
However, when I tried to run QFontDialog (native dialog) I got a font name Noto Rashi Hebrew. And so when I select it — it gives me an error on accepting the font:

qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 2142, resource id: 21682318, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor code: 0

The font name contains Hebrew so I presume that the font is for the Hebrew specific text. And using it on system that do not have this locale will just fail.
Is it possible to exclude unsupported fonts from being displayed?

Seriously, consider the vagueness of your question, and how almost nobody could properly answer to it. 1. "an error" -> what error? 2. what specific Linux distribution and configuration? 3. what Qt version? 4. are you using the native dialog? 5. the concept of "[un]supported font" is extremely ambiguous: supported by what?

@musicamante, answers added. Please check.

Please don't use comments as reference in the description without proper context. Take your time and properly edit your question by explaining all the above without forcing others to read the comments to understand what you're writing. Besides, the fact that a font contains "Hebrew" in its name does not make it automatically consistent with Hebrew writing system, and there are proper ways to check that (for instance, QFontMetrics::inFont(char)). I once had a couple of fonts named "Jurassic", which certainly didn't make them that old ;-)

@musicamante, I did edit the OP answering all those 5 points. Now are you familiar with that error? It appears when I select this font and click OK/press Enter.

I did read the edit, and what noted above still remains. I'd be more specific: 1. Does the error only happen for a specific font, for some, or all? 2. "Not sure about configuration" is useless: do some efforts and provide proper details about relevant config aspects; 3. as said, you shouldn't reference comments to give details without context (people should be able to understand the question before reading them), so clarify to what option you're referring to; 4. the default behavior is to use the native dialog, which implies that you may be using it; 6. "just fail" in doing what?

@musicamante, 1. It definitely don't happen for all of them and not 1 specific. 2. Are you looking for a kernel version, KDE version or what? Gentoo is not Ubuntu/RedHat/Debian. 3. I gave Qt version as requested. What else are you looking for? 4. OK. I thought by default all options are off. 5. It means it will produce the error from 1.

I know very well how Gentoo is different, since I've been using it for almost 20 years. That's why it's important to know the proper environment, not just the OS: are you on X11 or Wayland? Do you have KDE/Plasma elements installed? What window manager do you use? Also, does that error cause any consequences or does it just appear on terminal? Normally, XCB messages like that are caused by a multitude of factors that can often be ignored, as not critical. Thus, creating such an output but without crashing is probably not that relevant. In any case, try using the non native dialog as suggested.

@musicamante, I have X11 there and emerge full KDE Plasma but nothing extra. And I am using it as my WM. I didn't dive too deep into that. For now I see that message and wanted to see if anybody is familiar or point to the cause. And yes - I see it on the Terminal. I'll try to use non-native dialog as well

Ok, that's important to know, because Qt always tries the native dialog, even on Linux, if the system provides it (assuming it's properly configured: for instance, I use fluxbox, but I get KDE native dialogs); so, try the non native dialog, but consider that it may be an issue external to Qt itself (at least, to your side of the program). Still, you haven't answered the most important question :-) Despite the message, does it work? Filtering fonts may be possible, but only with the non native dialog (as it requires fixing the internal QFontComboBox).
